# get numbers from html to jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have numbers (in html text): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
And when i push on numbers i need get this numbers in jQuery. How this looks like? maybe somebody have sample?

In php this is easy:

```
echo $_GET['num'];
<a href = "index.php?num=1">1</a>
<a href = "index.php?num=2">2</a>
```

But how this makes with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```